# Is there a sass version of bootstrap 3 with em font sizes?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'd like to stick to Bootstrap 3 for compatibility with older browsers. However I need to have all font-sizes in em.

Has anyone seen a sass version with em font sizes instead of px?

Answer (score 0):

This might help you but it's a dirty solution by overriding the variables with `em` ones:
https://gist.github.com/jasny/9731895

You can still go through the main bootstrap file and change it localy.

Without knowing the reason for you to use `em` for font-sizes I suggest you go with `rem` if your browser version list can support it.

Comment: Thanks @George Antonakos. I did see that and it's not the best solution. I just ended up changing them myself to em's. I was curious to see if maybe I couldn't find it and it already existed. Guess not.